# Get Feature id in OpenLayers from GeoServer/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles, tile-map-service

With OpenLayers, I'm creating layers like ol.layer.VectorTile

```
var projection_epsg_name = 'EPSG:900913';
var geoserverLayerName = 'teste:map_shape2';

const tileLoadURL= 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + geoserverLayerName + '@' + projection_epsg_name + '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf';

// const tileLoadURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/geoserver/gwc/demo/teste:map_shape2?gridSet=EPSG:900913&format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile"
// const tileLoadURL = "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=" + geoserverLayerName + "&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=" + projection_epsg_name + ":{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=" + projection_epsg_name + "&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}";

var vectorSource = new ol.source.VectorTile({       
    tilePixelRatio: 1, 
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
    format: new ol.format.MVT(),
    url: tileLoadURL,
});

var vectorTile = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    style:styleFunction,
    source:vectorSource,
})

map.addLayer(vectorTile);
```

I need `id` to perform a query in the database, but I do not have this attribute. My data comes from PostGIS, and GeoServer is configured in such a way that it displays the `id`. How can I have this attribute using OpenLayers?

[image]

Comment: You probably need to make either a WFS request to get attributes back or a WMS getFeatureInfo request. There is no need to put an ID in vector tile vector so GeoServer doesn't

Comment: Strictly you don't have any features in a TMS, so difficult to see how you can fetch an id for them.

Comment: to use TMS, I installed the Vector Tile extension and followed the tutorial on that link: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html